# Question Expiration / Force Accept Answers

Tags: discussion, support

Looking through my answer history, there are a few answers that are empirically correct, but the user abandoned over a month ago.

What is the correct course of action for such instances? If the answer is to flag, should there be an option for this, or should I just use the "other" and fill out a note.

This applies to any old question you might come across with a correct answer but no acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked on [the main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8692/269301).

While I can't find why it got [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), I suspect it's because there's a lot of work involved to do right and it would make the idea of an accepted answer a lot more confusing. Kevin's answer on the linked post points somewhat in that direction as well.

Comment: It got declined because how the site is designed to work. Only the OP can accept an answer, but the question can be considered answered without the OP accepting an answer.

Comment: @Dom Yes, by voting the correct answer *should* rise to the top, regardless of whether it's an accepted answer or not.

Comment: Indeed, but there are many unaccepted but good answers that bias the community statistics.